# SQLite syntax incorrect near "S"

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have been working on a project using SQLite + C++ for a while now and I can't seem to get it to work. Right now, my code isn't showing anything in the console like it is supposed to. The error I get is `syntax incorrect near "S"`. My code is:

```
/*Definitions*/
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
void *arg;
char *err;
const char stmt = *"SELECT * from table";
/*End of Definitions*/

int exec(void *arg, int argc, char **argv, char **column) {
    while(true) {
        int i = 0;
        for(i < argc;) {
            cout << column[i] << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
        cout << "------" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &db); /*Open db "test.sqlite"*/
    if(!rc) {
        sqlite3_exec(db, &stmt, exec, arg, &err);
    }
    /*Ending Stuffz (NOTHING BEYOND THIS POINT)*/
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The database contains data in this table but it won't show. I had it working at one point but it only worked for one row then stopped. I was stupid and neglected backups and now I'm in this mess as I tried to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem starts in this line:

> ```
> const char stmt = *"SELECT * from table";
> ```

This creates a **single** `char` with the value `'S'` copied from the string literal, because the asterisk applied to the string literal like this simply gets you the first character of the `char const[]` and ignores the rest.

You then supply the address of the `char` object to SQLite here:

> ```
> sqlite3_exec(db, &stmt, exec, arg, &err);
> ```

The function expects a `char const*` as its second argument. Although [its documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) does not explicitly say so, it is naturally expecting a pointer to a null-terminated `char` array, not to a single `char`.

You are therefore running into **undefined behaviour** here, because the function keeps looking for the terminating `'\0'`, getting into memory it is not allowed to access.

You are also unlucky, because instead of crashing and thereby showing you where the error is, what apparently happens is that an accessible `'\0'` *just happens* to be there in memory right after the `'S'`.

So you are effectively **passing the single letter "S" as SQL string**, and the function complains correctly about that.

The cure is easy:

```
const char* stmt = "SELECT * from table";
```

[...]

```
sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, exec, arg, &err);
```

Comment: Thankyou! However, this fixes the first issue I list, but the problem where it outputs the first row only still persists. Is there any way you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @rEbOot: One issue/problem/bug per question please! :) Stack Overflow encourages you to ask separate questions for separate things.

Comment: I must wait before I can post again.